# Run text files in terminal

Tags: linux, list, command-line, terminal

Does anyone know if there's a way to run automatically in shell a list of commands (from a text file)?

I need to run a lot of scripts (around 1000). The scripts are in python and take 2 arguments each (dir_#, and sample#)

The text file I've made looks like this...

```
     python /home/name/scripts/get_info.py dir_1 sample1
     python /home/name/scripts/get_info.py dir_2 sample2
     python /home/name/scripts/get_info.py dir_3 sample3
     python /home/name/scripts/get_info.py dir_4 sample4
     ...
```

So, I would expect that passing this text file as argument to a command in terminal, could do the job automatically...

Thanks in advance,

peixe

Comment: The command you are looking for is `source`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's called a "shell script."

Add this to the top of your file:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Then execute this command:

```
chmod +x filename
```

Then execute it like a program:

```
./filename
```

Alternately, you can execute the shell directly, telling it to execute the commands in your file:

```
sh -e filename
```

Answer (score 9):

Also, you can run a shell file by:

```
source filename
```

Comment: i do not get, why this got a downvote...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786499/what-is-the-difference-between-sh-and-source

both kind of fits the need, especially if you need to define some variables for the session as well

Answer (score 6):

Either make the file executable:

```
chmod u+x thefile
./thefile
```

or run it as an argument of sh:

```
sh thefile
```

Comment: Simply making it executable won't work, unless the first line includes #!/bin/sh

Comment: That is not true, not with bash at least.

Comment: Perhaps not with bash, but I don't think we can assume everyone is using bash--your own answer doesn't assume that with "sh thefile" :)

Comment: AFAIK, scripts only need this directive to ensure a specific shell is used and is by no mean mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh

python /home/name/scripts/get_info.py dir_1 sample1
python /home/name/scripts/get_info.py dir_2 sample2
python /home/name/scripts/get_info.py dir_3 sample3
python /home/name/scripts/get_info.py dir_4 sample4
...
```