# shell script does not return any input

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created a shell script in a file named `strings` referring to that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script):

```
#! /bash/sh
original_string='i love Suzi and Marry'
string_to_replace_Suzi_with='Sara'
result_string="${original_string/Suzi/$string_to_replace_Suzi_with}"
```

after that I have created an executable file referring to that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545968/run-text-files-in-terminal):

```
chmod +x strings
```

but if I run the file like that:

```
./strings
```

I get the issue:

> ./strings: 5: ./strings: Bad substitution

How can that be possible? I have just copied and pasted the sample code.

Comment: sh is not same as bash

Comment: Probably find that sh is not an issue, but the space between the shebang (#!) and the fact that you have not provided a path to you interpreter is a problem, so #!/bin/sh should also work.  As mentioned below though, you would need to echo something to have output displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First line is not valid, change it to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

And it should work.

Comment: No I do not get no error message any more. But if I type './strings' the command line does not return anything and just jumps to a fresh prompt. Do I still miss something ?

Comment: You are not printing anything in your script. If you want to get the output of result_string, add `echo "$result_string"` at the end of your script.