# Can Execute Commands in Terminal But Not from Text File

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running code using Ubuntu on a WSL. Every time I edit some C files I need to execute a makefile and run an installer to ensure that the changes are reflected in the python package that I am using. The set of commands I need to execute is

```
make clean
make 
cd python
python setup.py install --user
```

This works perfectly when I execute them in the terminal. In order to make my life easier, I decided to put these commands in a text file `Compile.txt` to be executed whenever I need to compile the relevant files. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545968/run-text-files-in-terminal/6546018) and tried to replicate its solution. However, whenever I type `./Compile.txt` into the terminal I get the error

```
'.  Stop. No rule to make target 'clean
gcc      -o .o
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: .o] Error 1
./Compile.txt: line 7: cd: $'python\r': No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can anyone explain what I've done wrong? I apologise for any misuse of terminology as I'm still quite new to Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your `.txt` is in DOS format. convert it to UNIX format (e.g. using `dos2unix`).

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you so much.